# Is DNA a base inside the cell?

Tags: acid-base, chemical-biology, structural-biology, dna-rna

DNA is deoxyribonucleic *acid* because it has phosphate groups in every one of it's nucleotides.

However, in aqueous solutions protons will ionize, leaving phosphates alone as negative groups, i.e., lewis bases.

In this case, which is seen in all of our cells, is DNA structure actually the conjugate base of the theoretically described crystal form of DNA?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. If you have any questions about the site, feel free to visit the [help]. Best of luck with your interesting question!

Comment: In nuclei DNA as coniugated base is bound to histons which work as coniugated acid.

Comment: Related: [Why are lactate and lactic acid used synonymously in biochemistry?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61457/why-are-lactate-and-lactic-acid-used-synonymously-in-biochemistry)

Comment: In a solution of Hydrochloric acid, almost all of  $\ce{HCl}$ exists as $\ce{Cl-}$ which is a base. Would you call it Hydrochloric *base* instead?

Comment: By the way it's very related to pKa concept as I now understood it. DNA should be reduced to a bulk of phosphate groups for simplicity, of which the pKa value is ~3. Since we know that physiologic pH is ~7, ionized form of phosphate groups must have ten thousand times more concentration than the non-ionized form. That's how we know DNA is actually what makes the environment acidic. Otherwise I was thinking we might have very well defined DNA in it's ionized form, as DNB. But understanding why this would be wrong depends on understanding the pKa concept. So thanks @orthocresol.

Comment: The pH is 7, it's not really an acidic environment. In terms of charge it's simply balanced by a whole host of positively charged stuff, like histones (which Mithoron mentioned), but also cations like Mg2+, etc. The name DNA is, to some extent, a misnomer; DNA as it exists in the body is not an acid, since it exists mostly in the form of its conjugate base.

Comment: (As for whether it's different from the crystal structure, I am not sure whether Franklin crystallised DNA as the acid or as the salt, would have to look it up later. However you are certainly quite correct in saying that DNA exists as the conjugate base)

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24791/why-dna-is-negatively-charged-and-what-makes-it-so